# How can I dynamically create an xpath string in Python for a webdriver xpath selector?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python, xpath

I am writing a Selenium Webdriver test using python2.7 to use XPath to select a  link node set. For each link, I need to change the `href` attribute using `driver.execute_script` to execute javascript.

Trying to build the XPath string to vary the index in a separate loop.

The original statement which I need to build as a string and vary the index in a separate loop:

```py
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Comment')])[3]") 
xp_str1 = str("\"(//a[contains(text(),'Comment')])[")
xp_str2 = str(3)
xp_str3 = str("]\"")
str_elem = xp_str1 + xp_str2 + xp_str3

elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(str_elem)   
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].href = 'social_media/comment/type/peer/id/9999';", elem2)
```

I consistently get the webdriver error:

```
 InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'The given selector " //a[contains(text(),\'Comment\')])[3]" is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression "(//a[contains(text(),\'Comment\')])[3]" because of the following error:\n[Exception... "The expression cannot be converted to return the specified type."  code: "0" nsresult: "0x805b0034 (TypeError)"
```

Can any one give me ideas?

Comment: So your original statement works, but you're having trouble putting it into a loop?

Comment: The original statement works for each node in the set. I would like to dynamically generate the xpath string in order to vary the index (in this instance [3]) and test each member of the set. The loop shouldn't be a problem, but concatenating the xpath string and using it as a  string variable with webdriver (str_elem), seems to be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seems for me that you have too much quotation marks in here. I think

```
xp_str1 = str("//a[contains(text(),'Comment')])[")
xp_str2 = str(3)
xp_str3 = str("]")
str_elem = xp_str1 + xp_str2 + xp_str3
```

fixes this because when you use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Comment')])[3]")
```

quotation marks mean that argument or function is a string. And when you use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(str_elem)
```

the argument for function is string variable, so you don't need additional quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks (from the error) like it may have something to do with the extra '(' in your selector.  Given you state the original statement works:

```
elem2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Comment')])[3]")
```

and this is the bad one:

```
The given selector "(//a[contains(text(),\'Comment\')])[3]"
```

you can clearly see the difference when lined up.  You appear to have an extra '(' at the start.

I believe

```
xp_str1 = str("\"//a[contains(text(),'Comment')])[")
xp_str2 = str(3)
xp_str3 = str("]\"")
str_elem = xp_str1 + xp_str2 + xp_str3
```

may fix that.  I just tried it quickly in an [online interpreter](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~kwalsh/python/), and it appears to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Using the string assignment str_elem after removing the extra '(', still gives the same error. In fact without that '(', the syntax becomes unbalanced in the final string, the opening parentheses are 2 and the closing parentheses are 3. My problem remains.